# Integrate start module using Qt5 with a program using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, qt5

I built a software using tkinter as interface.
I found on internet a complementary module that could help and wanted to add it into my program.

The aim is to have a button that "launch" the module. It work by putting the all module into a function called by a button called 'Module'.

My issue is when I close the Qt5 windows, my tkinter is frozen.

I am quite sure that my strategy is not the best but I am not used to Qt5.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make tkinter and Qt5 work simultaneously ?

Thanks

Comment: How can we help without a [mre]?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.